# Use Xpath Inside XSLT test clause

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am trying to put xpath expression as a variable inside a xslt test clause, as follows:

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="../v:node[@InputName='{v:HeaderValue}']">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

However, it doesn't work, and always evaluates to false. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic XPath evaluation is not available in XSLT 1.0 or  in XSLT 2.0.

It may be available in **[XSLT 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/)** as (the currently proposed) **[`<xsl:evaluate>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate)** instruction

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do just this

```
<xsl:when test="../v:node[@InputName=v:HeaderValue]">
```

The { } notation is for Attribute Value Templates, which is used when creating attributes and you want the result of an expression as the value of the attribute.

Comment: TimC: I think the OP wants dynamic XPath evaluation.